# Rasterize fails when called inside an NMinimize expression

Tags: graphics, mathematical-optimization, rasterize

I'm trying to do an `NMinimize` based on images where the images are rasterized Graphics expressions that are parametrized by the `NMinimize` to build a discrete image that can be used to compute the objective function.

But for now the basic image rasterization step does not work inside the loop. I can't figure out why. It works fine outside.

Here is a minimal illustration of my problem. I put all created images inside a test array, and all of them are just red with nothing inside (see image bellow).

```
test = {};
NMinimize[
 {imgTest = Rasterize[Graphics[ Disk[ {x, y}, s]]];
  0 (* return 0, the problem is not here *)
  ,
  0.0 <= x <= 1000.0 && 0.0 <= y <= 1000.0 && 0.1 <= s <= 500.0}
 , {x, y, s},
 Method -> "NelderMead",
 EvaluationMonitor :> AppendTo[test, imgTest]]
```

[image: error]

I'm probably missing something, but just I can't figure out what...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Your problem is a very common one and was asked many times before. That's the reason we closed this as a duplicate, although Henrik gave you an answer for your specific case. Please don't feel discouraged by the closing of your question. It is a valid question and its only flaw is that it was answered several times already.

Comment: The specific answer in the rather long "Common Pitfalls" post you should look at [is this one here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/187).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the pattern `_?NumericQ` to shield your code from symbolic computations. Try

```
imgTest[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := (
  img = Rasterize[Graphics[Disk[{x, y}, s]]];
  0
  );
test = {};
NMinimize[
 {imgTest[x, y, s], 
  0.0 <= x <= 1000.0 && 0.0 <= y <= 1000.0 && 0.1 <= s <= 500.0}, {x, 
  y, s},
 Method -> "NelderMead", EvaluationMonitor :> AppendTo[test, img]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Henrik Schumacher, it's working!

Comment: You're welcome.